MudBlazor DataGrid Question - How to control the action of the auto generated save button
I am trying to teach myself MudBlazor since I got sick of dealing with all the CSS myself.  It is so nice and powerful, I am loving it!
I did run into a small problem though.  Say you want to use a DataGrid and have the columns automatically generate a form based on their model properties.  The code example is here:  https://www.mudblazor.com/components/datagrid#editing  Search for the Editing Example.
In the code, there is a small edit button and when you click it the auto generated form comes up.  There you have an accept and cancel button.  The question is:
How do you control the accept button in the auto-generated form?
I understand that I could change the OnClick property so it uses my own function but then the auto generated form will not come up.  I actually want to use it but I just need to control the action of the Accept button.  In the example they provide, the button correctly updates the List<T> but I need to push into the database.   the idea is to avoid iterating through 300-1000 items if it can be helped.
Thank you!
BMET1.
This picture Shows what I am talking about

@using System.Net.Http.Json @using MudBlazor.Examples.Data.Models @inject HttpClient httpClient

<MudDataGrid T="Element" Items="@Elements.Take(4)" ReadOnly="@_readOnly" EditMode="@(_isCellEditMode ? DataGridEditMode.Cell : DataGridEditMode.Form)"
    StartedEditingItem="@StartedEditingItem" CanceledEditingItem="@CanceledEditingItem" CommittedItemChanges="@CommittedItemChanges"
    Bordered="true" Dense="true" EditTrigger="@(_editTriggerRowClick ? DataGridEditTrigger.OnRowClick : DataGridEditTrigger.Manual)">
    <Columns>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Number" Title="Nr" IsEditable="false" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Sign" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Name" />
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Position">
            <EditTemplate>
                <MudSelect @bind-Value="context.Item.Position" Required RequiredError="You must select a Position!!!" Margin="@Margin.Dense">
                    <MudSelectItem Value="0">zero</MudSelectItem>
                    <MudSelectItem Value="1">one</MudSelectItem>
                    <MudSelectItem Value="17">seventeen</MudSelectItem>
                </MudSelect>
            </EditTemplate>
        </PropertyColumn>
        <PropertyColumn Property="x => x.Molar" Title="Molar mass" />
        <TemplateColumn Hidden="@(_isCellEditMode || _readOnly || _editTriggerRowClick)" CellClass="d-flex justify-end">
            <CellTemplate>
                <MudIconButton Size="@Size.Small" Icon="@Icons.Material.Outlined.Edit" OnClick="@context.Actions.StartEditingItemAsync" />
            </CellTemplate>
        </TemplateColumn>
    </Columns> </MudDataGrid>

<div class="d-flex flex-wrap mt-4">
    <MudSwitch @bind-Checked="@_readOnly" Color="Color.Primary">Read Only</MudSwitch>
    <div class="d-flex justify-start align-center">
        <p class="mud-typography mud-typography-body1 mud-inherit-text mr-2">Form</p>
        <MudSwitch @bind-Checked="@_isCellEditMode">Cell</MudSwitch>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex justify-start align-center">
        <p class="mud-typography mud-typography-body1 mud-inherit-text mr-2">Manual</p>
        <MudSwitch @bind-Checked="@_editTriggerRowClick">On Row Click</MudSwitch>
    </div> </div>

<MudExpansionPanels Style="flex:1">
    <MudExpansionPanel Text="Show Events">
        @foreach (var message in _events)
        {
            <MudText Typo="@Typo.body2">@message</MudText>
        }
        @if(_events.Count > 0) 
        {
            <div class="d-flex">
                <MudSpacer/>
                <MudButton Class="mt-3" ButtonType="ButtonType.Button" Variant="Variant.Filled" OnClick="@(() =>
_events.Clear())">Clear</MudButton>
            </div>
        }
    </MudExpansionPanel> </MudExpansionPanels>

@code {
    private IEnumerable<Element> Elements = new List<Element>();
    private bool _readOnly;
    private bool _isCellEditMode;
    private List<string> _events = new();
    private bool _editTriggerRowClick;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        Elements = await httpClient.GetFromJsonAsync<List<Element>>("webapi/periodictable");
    }

    // events
    void StartedEditingItem(Element item)
    {
        _events.Insert(0, $"Event = StartedEditingItem, Data = {System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(item)}");
    }

    void CanceledEditingItem(Element item)
    {
        _events.Insert(0, $"Event = CanceledEditingItem, Data = {System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(item)}");
    }

    void CommittedItemChanges(Element item)
    {
        _events.Insert(0, $"Event = CommittedItemChanges, Data = {System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(item)}");
    } }


Didn't quite understand the problem.. are you saying you cannot find a way to save the item that was just changed, to the database?

Hello @flackoverstow.
Yes, more or less.  MudBlazor will read the properties in the data model and auto-generate a form.   I could bypass it and create my own but it defeats the purpose of using MudBlazor.   The whole point is to use the auto form.
The auto-generated form has a button which I have no idea what function is calling or how to change it to suit my needs.
I do know that it changes the List in the model and I could iterate through it but that would be like asking me to update 300-1000 items to a database instead of just the one I clicked on.

The save button in this form:

Does some stuff internally to MB, and then MB invokes whatever EventCallback compatible thing you specified in the CommittedItemChanges="...", probably in the markup. When MB calls the method you supplied, it passes in the item that was changed
You would then perhaps use this to save your item to DB. Remember that best practice isn't to use your database entities directly here, so you'd perhaps have a code where you have a ViewModel type object that has properties and logic suited to your UI, and you filled an enumerable of those things when you loaded your page, then used that to drive the grid contents.
An example code to save could look like:
    async Task CommittedItemChangesAsync(UserViewModel uvm) //async, because it's doing DB IO
    {
        //let's assume you use EF Core and have correctly set up a context factory for your blazor server side app
        var context = await _contextFactory.CreateDbContextAsync();

        //pull down the user
        var u = await context.Users.FindAsync(uvm.Id);

        //copy the data across. You could use a mapper lib for this too
        if(u != default){
            u.Name = uvm.Name;
            u.Address = uvm.Address;
        }
        
        await context.SaveChangesAsync();
    }

If you're not writing server side, don't worry; it's not going to look significantly different, but that save operation would be in a controller endpoint on the server, and your WASM app would likely be calling that endpoint and supplying the uvm viewmodel

Thank you @flackoverstow,
What you describe is exactly what I did but by the time you get the object in the last function the list has been modified.  This is bad because if the pushing to the db fails, the list is not up to date.  Granted, I can implement checks but that requires more logic.  I already had these checks in place on through a database service so having to rewrite them is a bit a pain.
It would had been easier to control what the accept button does in the first place.

I didn't understand when you said "list is modified" - the list isn't modified, the items within the list are modified. What logic are you wanting for "what the accept button does"? Of course, this is like anything else: my hard disk is full, I open a word doc, I add 100 words, I cannot save the document because the disk is full.. but word still shows me the draft 100 words I wrote. I need to resolve the problem and save the data. Same here; your list of items is edited by MB, you just have to save it. If it fails, fix the problem with the saving. What problem could there be?

I think I found a suitable way to do it.  It's not the way I was hoping but it will do in a pinch.
In the example code, there is a callback function called CommittedItemChanges.  You would change the Element type with the one of your class of course, and simple push "item" to the DB inside the function.
void CommittedItemChanges(YourClass item)
    {

//Insert code for pushing item into the DB here. 

//Replace _events.Insert()... with your on logging solution if needed: 
        _events.Insert(0, $"Event = CommittedItemChanges, Data = {System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Serialize(item)}");
    } }

If someone knows of a better way please let me know.  I would love to know a bit more.  The only drawback with the way I found is that it's still messing with the List but there is not much you can do about that.  You will have to use the other functions provided to create a temporary saved item.

It was the source of my confusion; your question implied you had that code, so you could already get access to the item that MB just "saved" and you could put it to DB at that point.. How it is "messing with the list" ? When you commit an edit, yout code is called in void CommittedItemChanges(Element item) with the changed model object passed in; you can load that item from the DB, map the changed data to the DB entity and save it again. There is no "list" there - the example code features an _events list but that's notionally no different to Console.WriteLine just showing activity

@flackoverstow by the time you get that item you have already saved to the List, but the db itself has it's own rules and it may reject the save/update request.  For this reason I wanted to avoid doing that in the first place and have access to the Accept button in the auto form.

Oh, but the item in the list represents the user's draft; let them make it, tell them if there is a problem saving the data, don't destroy their draft, let them open it back up again and fix it. MB will always let them edit the draft, but whether the draft is saved or not is down to if the DB accepts it.. You can control that part of the process, and just treat their input in the list item as their efforts that you will attempt to save..
